# How to find the total number of occurrences of text and files with find command

Tags: shell, grep, find, search

I am trying to run the `find` command to find the total number of occurrences of a particular text string and also the number of files which has this text string.

What I have right now is this command.

`find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "abc"`

This reports all the "*.txt" files which contain the text "abc". I want either one or two find command to get

1. Total number of times abc appears
2. Total number of files which has abc in it.

Comment: for the sake of precision: your command (and all the other grep based solutions) do not display the number of occurrences of the text string but the number of lines where the string occurres at least once

Comment: @miracle173 Good point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For question 1, you can do this:

`find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "abc" | wc -l`

This counts the total number of matches for **abc** in all text files.

And for question 2, I came up with:

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -i "abc" {} + | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l`

This gets just the unique filenames from the list of matches and counts them (the sort is probably not needed).

---

As pointed out by miracle173, `grep` comes with a "one match per file" flag so the command can be shortened to just:

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -il "abc" {} + | wc -l`

Comment: 2. is a little bit complicated. grep -l will display one line for each file containing the search string.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen Thanks for your answer. The first one works but for the second one looks like you are missing something after wc -. I am getting this error  wc: cannot open -  find: bad option out

Comment: @Nomad There was a missing character at the end.

Comment: @miracle173 I'm not surprised there's a shorter answer. I didn't know about `grep -l` to be honest. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Guys thanks to everyone, who contributed to this question, for your time and help. I will tryout the suggestions and will come back here with update.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen, so which command is which now. Looks like find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -il "abc" {} + | wc -l brings the number of occurrence and find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "abc" | wc -l brings number of files. Can you please explain or update your answer with more clarification. Thanks

Comment: It should be as per my original answer.

Answer (score 3):

grep's `-c` option is what you need here

```
find . -name \*txt | xargs grep -c -i "abc" | {
    total=0
    count=0 
    while IFS=: read name num; do 
        ((num > 0)) && ((count+=1))
        ((total+=num))
    done
    echo total=$total 
    echo count=$count
}
```

The braces to group the commands around the `while` loop are required to keep the variables in one scope for that subshell.

Comment: `count`contains the number of files found by `find . -name \*txt` and not the number files containing the string because `grep -c` returng `0` if the string is not found in a file.

Comment: @miracle173, quite right. answer updated.

Comment: @glenn jackman, your solution is very elegant and one stop approach. I like it. Plus it works :).

Comment: @glenn jackman, your solution is great but for sometimes i was getting error for it, otherwise i would have accepted your answer. But thank you so much for your help and answer, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nomad, what errors?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -R --include='*.txt' -c -i abc . | awk -F: ' 
           BEGIN {
                    totalCount=0;noOfFiles=0;
                 } 
                 { totalCount=totalCount+$2; 
                   if ( $2 > 0 ) 
                   {
                       noOfFiles+=1;
                   } 
                 } 
            END {
             print "Total number of times abc appears:"totalCount; 
             print "Total number of files which has abc in it:"noOfFiles
            } '
```

**(OR)**

ls output should not be used to parsed by other programs. See the comment below.

```
$  ls -Rltr | awk '/.txt/{print $NF }' | xargs grep -c -i "abc" | awk -F: ' 
       BEGIN {
                totalCount=0;noOfFiles=0;
             } 
             { totalCount=totalCount+$2; 
               if ( $2 > 0 ) 
               {
                   noOfFiles+=1;
               } 
             } 
        END {
         print "Total number of times abc appears:"totalCount; 
         print "Total number of files which has abc in it:"noOfFiles
        } '


Result:
Total number of times abc appears:0
Total number of files which has abc in it:0
```

Comment: This command won't find text files in subdirectories (unless the directory has a `.txt` extension).

Comment: The answer that relies on `ls -R` doesn't work (the output of `ls -R` is not full paths! And retaining only the last word does nothing, except further mangle file name with spaces), and [you shouldn't parse the output of ls anyway](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @anon_anon, i tried your both commands and they don't work.

grep: illegal option -- R
grep: illegal option -- include=*.txt
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
awk: syntax error near line 2
awk: bailing out near line 2

Comment: @Gilles actually, I had an alias ls="ls -ltr", Hence the error. Fixed the issue, but as you said ls output should not be parsed. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nomad I am not exactly sure, but can you check if the following match? The command is working for me.

`$ shopt | grep 'on$'
cmdhist         on
expand_aliases  on
extquote        on
force_fignore   on
hostcomplete    on
interactive_comments    on
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
sourcepath      on`

Answer (score 1):

#### Number of abc's contained in files:

To count the number of all "abc"'s in the .txt files, use grep -c and find and - exceptionally - cat:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + | grep -ic abc
```

Grep -c will do the total count for you - something I didn't find in SigueSigueBen's answer, which contains unjustified calls to `xargs`, imho. The other 2 answers where to long for me. I didn't study them and wouldn't write such things myself.

#### Number of files containing abc:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -iq abc {} ";" -printf "1" | wc -c
```

This will not fail with filenames (which are rarely, I admit) containing newlines in their name (which is perfectly legal).