# Is more or find more resource intensive in finding the number of times an item lists in a file?

Tags: find, resources, more

I recently read [How to find the total number of occurrences of text and files with find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37874/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-occurrences-of-text-and-files-with-find-command), which asked about a way to find the number of times text "abc" appears in a file. The answer there provided the command `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "abc" | wc -l` to find the count.

Previously I have used something like `more "file_name*" |grep "abc" |wc -l` to list the number if times text "abc" appears in a specific file(s).

I tried this and found that the `more` command returned faster, but seemed to use ~30% more CPU (I was also monitoring via `top`) than the `find` command.

I was wondering if anyone had some more solid data on which of these two commands would be more intensive on resources if you were to query through approximately 15 files?  How about 30+ files?

Comment: @manatwork Yes, I ran one command in the same directory on the same files, then I ran the other right after it finished.

Comment: If you have a fast hard disk and multi-core CPU, you can make the find statement faster (but it will burn your CPU and hard disk bandwidth resources). Example of xargs running 4 concurrent process for the grep command: `find . -print0 -name "*.txt" | xargs -0 -P 4 grep -i "abc" | wc -l` The combination of `-print0` and `xargs -0` helps with filenames containing spaces!

Comment: Are you aware that when `more` displays multiple files, it inserts a header with the file name before each file's content? So if one of your files' name contains the string you search for, `grep`ing in `more`'s output will find extra occurrences in the file names. To avoid this, better use `cat`.

Comment: Thanks @Huygens!  I don't believe any of the files I was searching through had spaces in the name (simply because files with spaces almost always cause some sort of issue), but thank you for the input! The `xargs -P 4` is what will create 4 separate instances of the command to run?

Comment: Take such comparisons with caution! The system has a cache, the HDD has a cache - at least perform the test multiple times, and in opposite order.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `more` (or `cat`) if you have the list of file you need to grep: just give `grep` the files as an argument (no need to pipe the data through a second tool):

```
grep -i abc *.txt | wc -l
```

The main difference is that `find` will not only list the files in the current directory (as the shell expansion of `*.txt`) but it will recurse into subdirectories too:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i abc | wc -l
```

In the second case if there are some `*.txt` files in subdirectories these are also supplied as arguments to the `grep` command.

And by the way `grep` has a `-c` option to count the occurrences (no need for `wc` either)

```
grep -c -i abc *txt
```

also it will just give the number of occurrences per file and not the total

Comment: This is good to know as well! The way I was initially taught to search through files was by using `more` and piping in `grep`. I've never used `grep` as much of a standalone command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have "solid data", but consider this.

`more` is a (primitive) filter for paging through text one screenful at a time. It's intent is to be used interactively "for crt viewing". So even though you are sending the output to a `pipe`, it is still using the memory and CPU resources to display the each file to you with the filtering features `more` offers.

It would be more correct in your example to use `cat` rather than `more`. Taken a step further, your example command can be made even more efficient by dropping the additional step of going through a filtering program and have `grep` directly search through the files (instead of piping the output to it).

In regards to the `find` command being slower, `find` is also traversing the directory structure starting from `.` whereas `more` is only working on "file_name*" in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for the information!  I never really knew the difference from commands such as `more` and `cat`, so this is very helpful.

Comment: No `cat` is not more correct, it is as useless as `more`. You can just give the files to process as arguments to `grep`. `grep abc *.txt`. There is no need to involve an additional too.

Comment: @Matteo Good point.

Answer (score 1):

It only looks at first sight like a attempt for the useless use of cat award, but if we cat all files, before invoking grep:

```
cat *.txt | grep -ci abc
```

grep counts the sum for you. Since you like to traverse subdirectories (you like to, don't you?), you can do it there too:

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + | grep -ci abc
```